# Why did Thanos get the soul stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War* Red Skull tells Thanos that he must kill someone he loves in order to obtain the soul stone.

But if you truly loved the person you would never kill them. Can someone explain this paradox?

Comment: *"But if you truly loved the person you would never kill them."* --  ..is completely subjective, and will invoke mostly opinion based responses. As of now, VTC.

Comment: [Haven't you met Ego?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/73075/11244)

Answer (score 35):

> if you truly loved the person you would never kill them

This is, I think, overly simplistic and I think you missed the point of that scene.

Thanos killed Gamora *despite* loving her....because, in his mind, it was for the **greater good of the universe**.

That's why it was called a **sacrifice**.

---

Gamora was convinced that Thanos *couldn't love anyone* and this would be the fatal flaw in his quest.

Then she realises, in the same instant, that she's both wrong (and he does love her..and is quite possibly the *only* thing he loves) and he's going to kill her anyway!

Comment: Exactly this. Consider also what Gamora asked Quill to do. Quill, by all accounts, **loves Gamora** and she asked him to kill her - which he would have done had Thanos not turned his bullets into bubbles.